# Is Oracle's CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function really a function?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, syntax

I was under the impression that argument-less functions can be called with empty parentheses after the function name, i.e. what some other databases allow to do:

```
current_timestamp()
```

Whereas in Oracle, I have to write

```
current_timestamp
```

With user-defined functions, this rule doesn't apply (in 11g). I can write both

```
my_function
my_function()
```

**My question is:** Is [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions045.htm#i999217) really a true function or should I consider it to be a language construct / pseudo-column of the Oracle SQL dialect (compatible with the SQL standard)? Is there any formal definition about when I can (optionally, mandatorily) add the `()` and when I have to omit them?

Background-info:

- [SQL 1992](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) defines:

  ```
  <current timestamp value function> ::=
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP [ <left paren> <timestamp precision> <right paren> ]
  ```
- Derby, HSQLDB, Ingres, Postgres, SQLite, SQL Server behave like Oracle, where there are no parentheses allowed for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
- Sybase SQL Anywhere knows a `CURRENT TIMESTAMP` function (without parentheses, without underscore)
- CUBRID, MySQL, Sybase ASE allow for using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: FWIW select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() is a syntax error in MSSQL (i.e. only plain CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is acceptable)

Comment: @nonnb: Yes, you're right. I'll update the question with some background info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL standards back to 1992 refer to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as both a "time-varying system variable" and a "datetime value function". See, for example, [Database Language SQL](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).

But AFAIK the standards always use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, *never* CURRENT_TIMESTAMP().  Using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() on a compliant dbms should fail with a syntax error.

I'm not sure what the standards have to say about user-defined functions.

Comment: `time-varying system variable` is the term I was looking for. Great, thanks for the hint!