# Standard current time function using JDBC

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc

When we work with JPA and JPQL we can use some [date/time expressions](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/date) which make the query DMBS independent. For instance let's say if I want to set the ending time of a session in my database I could simply use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` expression as follows:

```
String jpql = "UPDATE SessionJpa s SET s.end = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE s.id = :id";

entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
query.setParameter("id", someIdValue);
query.executeUpdate();
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

This way the same JPQL should work with Oracle, MySQL, PostreSQL, etc as DBMS.

Now my question: Is there a way to achieve the same when using JDBC instead of JPA?

This is what I have so far:

```
String sql = "UPDATE Sessions SET end = SYSDATE WHERE id = ?";

try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    statement.setLong(1, someIdValue);
    int updatedRows = statement.executeUpdate();
    // ...
} catch(SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SessionsBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

But of course `SYSDATE` is not a generic expression and it will work only with Oracle as DBMS most likely.

Comment: AFAIK most database engines have CURRENT_TIMESTAMP implemented, but not sure if is 100% generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a related discussion here - [Is Oracle's CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function really a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10084967/738746).

Summary is that - `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is defined by the SQL standard and any compliant database system should recognize it.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from the fact that most databases have the SQL standard `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, JDBC drivers might support the JDBC escape functions and translate those to the database specific variant. These escapes are called using `{fn <function>}`, and are listed in Appendix C of the [JDBC 4.2 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-eval-spec/index.html).

Specifically (from C.3):

> `CURRENT_DATE[()]` Synonym for `CURDATE()`
>   `CURRENT_TIME[()]` Synonym for `CURTIME()`
>   `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP[()]` Synonym for `NOW()`
>   `CURDATE()` The current date as a date value
>   `CURTIME()` The current local time as a time value
>   `NOW()` A timestamp value representing the current date and time

So the JDBC escape equivalent would be:

```
String sql = "UPDATE Sessions SET end = {fn CURRENT_TIMESTAMP} WHERE id = ?";
```

(or `{fn NOW()}`)

Note that although JDBC drivers are required to support the escape syntax, they are not actually required to support all functions. Check the result of [`DatabaseMetaData.getTimeDateFunctions()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTimeDateFunctions--) for your driver.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same by defining another parameter for the date, such as:

```
String sql = "UPDATE Sessions SET end = ? WHERE id = ?";
...
statement.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()));
statement.setLong(2, sesion.getId());
```

I hope this works

Comment: You mean `new java.sql.Timestamp`. `java.sql.Date` only stores date, not date and time.

Comment: This is not exactly the same as doing current_timestamp on the db server. Plus `java.sql.Date` is not the equivalent of the timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jorge_B, I certainly tried it successfully but I'd prefer to rely on db server (not the bean container) setting the appropriate timestamp.