# Hibernates current_date and date_trunc

Tags: java, hibernate

Learning Hibernate's functionality and struck on a problem finding something, that would represent Oracle's:

> trunc(someDate) < trunc(sysdate) // aka 01.02.2017 00... < 01.02.2017
>   00...

or a postgres representative:

> date_trunc('day',someDate) < current_date

I guess there must be something in Hibernate's Criteria.

Comment: Have a look at [“Generic” current time function using JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611467/generic-current-time-function-using-jdbc). You should be able to use JDBC escape functions in native (SQL) queries.

Comment: But how to do it using hibernates HQL?

Comment: You  probably need to create a HQL query where you give the current date as a query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

in similar situation I used native query.

```
date_trunc('day', some_date)
```

or for the next day

```
date_trunc('day', some_date) + (interval '1 day')
```