# Is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP a function in ANSI SQL?

Tags: sql, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ansi-sql-92

I was using the bigquery function `current_timestamp()` when i discovered that you can use it without parenthesis if you want. Since it is a function, i would advocate for parenthesis, but what i find on the internet indicates that you can indeed use it without in different standards.

I found that in ANSI SQL 1992 it is indeed a function ([based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084967/is-oracles-current-timestamp-function-really-a-function)).
Yet i did not find why it is allowed to call it without parenthesis and even if the standard advocates for parenthesis or not ?
[Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/current_timestamp.html) is saying that it allows for a call without parenthesis to comply with ANSI SQL...

So does anyone knows what it is ?

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: i am just curious - how does it matter if you have () or not.

Comment: It's just clearer to me the type of what i'm using. If it's a function it should have a `()` at the end of the call, if it's a variable then it does not have a parenthesis since it's not a function call.
I guess i'm just being influenced by my knowledge of OOP and Java. 
The truth is in that case it does not really matter, but i would want to standardize it across an organization and therefore i seek what is the most appropriate standard to use :)

Comment: Lookup here - might be helpful for curiosity..
https://blog.ansi.org/2018/10/sql-standard-iso-iec-9075-2016-ansi-x3-135/

Comment: Thanks ! The documents are quite expensive though :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [2.1.2.70 F411](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_standards/ms-tsqliso02/44576eaf-36d6-4c23-92d8-ce6647101fb1):

> ```
> <current timestamp value function> ::=
>  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP [ <left paren> <timestamp precision> <right paren> ]
> ```

It is a function and `(<precision>)` is optional so the following are correct:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3);
```

Based on that definition `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` shouldn't work but often is implemented.

[db<>fiddle demo - MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ab97d08f39692f0cd5145e523917de6) vs [db<>fiddle demo - PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0ab97d08f39692f0cd5145e523917de6)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, very clear ! :)